# Put UISearchBar in the middlel of navagation bar, no table view is shown when typing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

I set UISearchBar as view controller's titleView. When I type in UISearchBar, no table view is shown.But before I set UISearchBar as view controller's titleView, everything works well.

```
 - (void)initSearchBar
{
    self.searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
    self.searchBar.barStyle     = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.searchBar.translucent  = YES;
    self.searchBar.delegate     = self;
    self.searchBar.placeholder  = @"搜索";
    self.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

    self.navigationItem.titleView=self.searchBar;
}

- (void)initSearchDisplay
{
    self.displayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.displayController.delegate                = self;
    self.displayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.displayController.searchResultsDelegate   = self;

}
```

Comment: are you using UISearchDisplayController ?

Answer (score 0):

when we Use UISearchDisplayController that's time UISearchDisplayController  call its own          tableView so we need to check condition .

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    return [searchAllData count];

}else{
    return [arrData count];

}

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

cell.textLabel.text=[searchAllData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}else{
cell.textLabel.text=[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }


}
```

Comment: I don't have other table view except searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView

Comment: UISearchDisplayController Contain its own table view when we search after that data are loaded in searchResultsTableView .@nimingzhe2008